# How to make custom header view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I started a project with storyboards and it has a lot of views, each one of them has the same header (with an image, company name and two buttons). I want to do this once in the main View, and make it reusable for the other views.

Comment: You can create a custom header view and use it where ever you want.

Comment: thanks...I know this way but don't know how to achieve it. More detail answer would be appreciable.

Comment: What are you showing in the header which is repeated in all the views? Only the image of some labels?

Comment: I am having custom back button on each view so I want to put it into main view and make it reusable in all other views.I can subview in every view but how to achieve event (poptoviewcontroller)?

Comment: Yes, Header is same for all the views.

Comment: Are you easy to share that view screenshot?

Comment: I posted below my custom header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66624/discussion-between-parvezkhan-and-adeel-ur-rehman).

Comment: Please remove your answer and post it in your question.

Comment: @Parvezkhan I have implemented a demo for you, you'r welcome to try it out!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a containing view controller with your header. Then, add your current root view controller (the current initial view controller in your storyboard) to this containing view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom view named HeaderView with XIB:

in HeaderView.h you have to define a protocol and the properties related to controls you want to display in header.

```
@protocol HeaderViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)onBackButtonTapped;
@end

@interface HeaderView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *headerImageView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <HeaderViewDelegate> delegate;

-(IBAction)backButtonTapped:(id)sender;

@end
```

In Header.m:

```
@implementation HeaderView

-(IBAction)backButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    if (delegate != nil && [delegate respondToSelector:@selector(onBackButtonTapped)])
    {
        [delegate onBackButtonTapped];
    }
}

@end
```

Now what you have to do is to create a BaseViewController and every controller should be extended from this controller in order to show the same header in all the views.

Let me know you have any questions regarding the implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66653/discussion-between-adeel-ur-rehman-and-parvezkhan).

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to create reusable views according to this [post](http://onedayitwillmake.com/blog/2013/07/ios-creating-reusable-uiviews-with-storyboard/).

- Create a class named SharedView which extends UIView
- Create a nib with the same name
- Set the ‘File’s Owner’ property in the nib to the SharedView class
- Create an outlet from your view to the SharedView class, and call it ‘contentView’
- Replace initWithCoder with the following:

  ```
  -(void)awakeFromNib {
      //Note that you must change @”BNYSharedView’ with whatever your nib is named
      [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BNYSharedView" owner:self options:nil];
      [self addSubview: self.contentView];
  }
  ```
- In your ViewControllers create views, and set their class to SharedView

Another solution is to use [**Container View Controller**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html), and as to your specific situation, I have tried to implement a [demo](https://github.com/lmnbeyond/ContainerView) for you, please try  it!

Hope it could help!

Comment: Add the handling of back button

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use NavigationController as rootviewControoler with leftBarbutton and rightbarButton 
so that it can be in your whole app